# The pow() function isn't working on CLion

Tags: c, clion

So I'm new to this whole thing but and using a YouTube tutorial but for some reason my pow function isn't working. For example:

```
printf ("%d", pow(4, 3));
```

It should be %d as I'm getting a double right? I tried %d but that didn't work.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'pow'
```

Help a newbie out, cheers.

Comment: I tried that but it still didnt work

Comment: You may need to include math.h

Comment: You need to `#include <math.h>` and you need to use the proper format code in `printf`.  You will probably also need to link with `-lm`.  Note that `pow` takes two `double` arguments and returns a `double` result.

Comment: it says that its an undeclared identifier

Comment: @SubashPariyar Follow my instructions.  One more time:  (1) `#include <math.h>` (2) Use `%f` and (3) link with `-lm` (or however it's done on your platform).  Three steps.

Comment: @SubashPariyar Read what I said:  *link* with `-lm`.  Linking is the final step in producing an executable.  It combines a set object files and libraries.  `-lm` tells it to link with the math library.  If you don't, it won't find `pow`.  In `gcc` you'd do `gcc myprog.c -lm` for example (that would compile `myprog.c` and link the result, along with the math library).  `CLion` must have something comparable.  Try it.

Comment: It's shame to blame CLion when you just don't know C. The error on hover in IDE clearly say `Implicitly declaring library function 'pow' with type 'double (double, double)'
include the header <math.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'pow'`

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old question but the answer doesn't actually solve the question, so for posterity here's the answer.

using Clion you'll need to first add `#include <math.h>` to your code e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main() {
    double a, b;
    a = 2.0;
    b = 4.0;

    printf("2.0^4.0 = %f", pow(a, b));

    return 0;
}
```

the 2nd thing is you'll need to add target_link_libraries(<target_name> m) in CMakeLists.txt
e.g.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(example C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(example main.c)
target_link_libraries(example m)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the math library.
For this, add to the beginning not only the standard input/output library, but also the math library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

Comment: they'll need to add the add target_link_libraries(<target_name> m) in CMakeLists.txt too as the question specified CLion